# could not bind value '1234' to parameter: 1; Invalid parameter index 1

Tags: sql-server-2008, hibernate, stored-procedures

I'm trying to execute stored procedure from hibernate. I'm new to hibernate let me know if there is any mistake in my code.

mapping hbm file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <sql-query name="callcopyDocumentStoredProcedure">
        <return alias="document" class="com.common.Document" />
        [exec copyDocument (:param1, :param2, :param3, :param4, :param5 ,:param6 ,:param7)]
    </sql-query>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Code I'm executing

```
Query copy= session.getNamedQuery("callcopyDocumentStoredProcedure");
copy.setParameter("param1", 1234);
copy.setParameter("param2", 12);
copy.setParameter("param3", 12);
copy.setParameter("param4", 0);
copy.setParameter("param5", 0);
copy.setParameter("param6", 1);
copy.setParameter("param7", 12);

List result = copy.list();
for(int i=0; i<result.size(); i++){
    Document newDocument = (Document)result.get(i);
    System.out.println(newDocument.getId());
}
```

What is wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

The right syntax for sp call is `{call copyDocument (:param1, :param2, :param3, :param4, :param5 ,:param6 ,:param7)}` as describer [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html#sp_query)